Restoring duplicity backup files stored on Google Drive. "ERROR 30 CollectionsError "
I'm trying to restore my hard drive from backups I created with deja-dup and stored on a Google Drive. I am able to point deja-dup to the correct GDdrive folder and it recognizes my backups (i.e. there are several entries for "Date" in the bottom right-hand corner.)
However, after processing for a few minutes, I see the error "No backup files found" on the Deja-Dup GUI. When I run it with DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1, the terminal outputs the following:
DUPLICITY: ERROR 30 CollectionsError
DUPLICITY: . Traceback (innermost last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in <module>
DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 75, in with_tempdir
DUPLICITY: .     fn()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1568, in main
DUPLICITY: .     do_backup(action)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1655, in do_backup
DUPLICITY: .     list_current(col_stats)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 708, in list_current
DUPLICITY: .     sig_chain = col_stats.get_signature_chain_at_time(time)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_collections.py", line 1035, in get_signature_chain_at_time
DUPLICITY: .     raise CollectionsError(u"No signature chains found")
DUPLICITY: .  duplicity.dup_collections.CollectionsError: No signature chains found
DUPLICITY: . 

This is the debug report from Deja-Dup:
System Details:
OS=Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Desktop=ubuntu
Locale=en_US.UTF-8
Home=/home/yndchrqw
Version=42.9
Tool Name=Duplicity
Tool Version=0.8.21

GSettings:
[org.gnome.DejaDup]
prompt-check='2024-09-19T15:07:01.843450Z'
include-list=['/home/yndchrqw/kmwtitkpt']
delete-after=90
last-restore='2024-09-20T04:09:57.839250Z'
backend='local'

[org.gnome.DejaDup.Local]
folder='fsrwhide-enwtiq-pqyn-ml'

[org.gnome.DejaDup.Google]
folder='fsrwhide-enwtiq-pqyn-ml'

[org.gnome.DejaDup.Drive]
folder=''
uuid='507A20A12FB2A684'
name='ijglglr mgdwdidw jd'
icon='. GThemedIcon drive-harddisk-usb drive-harddisk drive drive-harddisk-usb-symbolic drive-harddisk-symbolic drive-symbolic'

Latest Duplicity Log:
DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Feb 15 10:28:16 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Feb 15 10:28:16 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 15 10:28:16 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 15 10:28:16 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 15 10:28:16 2024 / end_time: Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024 / end_time: Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024 / end_time: Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024 / end_time: Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024 / end_time: Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024 / end_time: Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024 / end_time: Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024 / end_time: Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024 / end_time: Fri Apr 19 11:28:44 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Fri Apr 19 11:28:44 2024 to pre-existing chain [Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024]-[Fri Apr 19 11:28:44 2024]

DEBUG 1 
. Found backup chain [Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024]-[Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024]

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024; needed: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024; needed: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024)

INFO 1 
. Ignoring incremental Backupset (start_time: Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024; needed: Fri Apr 19 11:28:44 2024)

INFO 1 
. Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024 / end_time: Thu May  2 10:31:53 2024)

DEBUG 1 
. Added set Thu May  2 10:31:53 2024 to pre-existing chain [Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024]-[Thu May  2 10:31:53 2024]

WARNING 5 
. Warning, found incomplete backup sets, probably left from aborted session

NOTICE 1 
. Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.

NOTICE 1 
. Last full backup date: Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024

INFO 3 
backend BackendWrapper
archive-dir (. dir)
chain-no-sig 0
 full 20230724T020625Z 3293 enc
 inc 20230809T223503Z 75 enc
 inc 20230810T193404Z 42 enc
 inc 20230817T195905Z 32 enc
 inc 20230824T153515Z 45 enc
 inc 20230831T161127Z 52 enc
 inc 20230907T135352Z 51 enc
 inc 20230916T151834Z 44 enc
 inc 20230921T145917Z 51 enc
 inc 20230928T135829Z 74 enc
 inc 20231005T143110Z 26 enc
 inc 20231012T184132Z 42 enc
chain-no-sig 1
 full 20231024T155943Z 3372 enc
 inc 20231102T153517Z 26 enc
 inc 20231109T151217Z 29 enc
 inc 20231116T161724Z 46 enc
 inc 20231130T172436Z 43 enc
 inc 20231207T180847Z 479 enc
 inc 20231214T144925Z 36 enc
 inc 20231221T171045Z 46 enc
 inc 20231228T180905Z 16 enc
 inc 20240104T170422Z 25 enc
 inc 20240111T162415Z 40 enc
 inc 20240118T163957Z 34 enc
chain-no-sig 2
 full 20240125T145441Z 3822 enc
 inc 20240202T002124Z 23 enc
 inc 20240208T153948Z 45 enc
 inc 20240215T162816Z 41 enc
 inc 20240222T161209Z 32 enc
 inc 20240229T152502Z 18 enc
 inc 20240307T160117Z 58 enc
 inc 20240314T144059Z 41 enc
 inc 20240321T145508Z 51 enc
 inc 20240331T171212Z 31 enc
 inc 20240404T164118Z 25 enc
 inc 20240411T153802Z 56 enc
 inc 20240419T162844Z 40 enc
chain-no-sig 3
 full 20240426T161058Z 3872 enc
 inc 20240502T153153Z 32 enc
orphaned-sets-num 0
incomplete-sets-num 1
. Collection Status
. -----------------
. Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
. Archive dir: /home/yndchrqw/.cache/deja-dup/vgsnmsvutddoxjgxxabmpyjqttjegflw
. 
. Found 4 secondary backup chains.
. Secondary chain 1 of 4:
. -------------------------
. Chain start time: Sun Jul 23 21:06:25 2023
. Chain end time: Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023
. Number of contained backup sets: 12
. Total number of contained volumes: 3827
.  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
.                 Full         Sun Jul 23 21:06:25 2023              3293
.          Incremental         Wed Aug  9 17:35:03 2023                75
.          Incremental         Thu Aug 10 14:34:04 2023                42
.          Incremental         Thu Aug 17 14:59:05 2023                32
.          Incremental         Thu Aug 24 10:35:15 2023                45
.          Incremental         Thu Aug 31 11:11:27 2023                52
.          Incremental         Thu Sep  7 08:53:52 2023                51
.          Incremental         Sat Sep 16 10:18:34 2023                44
.          Incremental         Thu Sep 21 09:59:17 2023                51
.          Incremental         Thu Sep 28 08:58:29 2023                74
.          Incremental         Thu Oct  5 09:31:10 2023                26
.          Incremental         Thu Oct 12 13:41:32 2023                42
. -------------------------
. 
. Secondary chain 2 of 4:
. -------------------------
. Chain start time: Tue Oct 24 10:59:43 2023
. Chain end time: Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024
. Number of contained backup sets: 12
. Total number of contained volumes: 4192
.  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
.                 Full         Tue Oct 24 10:59:43 2023              3372
.          Incremental         Thu Nov  2 10:35:17 2023                26
.          Incremental         Thu Nov  9 09:12:17 2023                29
.          Incremental         Thu Nov 16 10:17:24 2023                46
.          Incremental         Thu Nov 30 11:24:36 2023                43
.          Incremental         Thu Dec  7 12:08:47 2023               479
.          Incremental         Thu Dec 14 08:49:25 2023                36
.          Incremental         Thu Dec 21 11:10:45 2023                46
.          Incremental         Thu Dec 28 12:09:05 2023                16
.          Incremental         Thu Jan  4 11:04:22 2024                25
.          Incremental         Thu Jan 11 10:24:15 2024                40
.          Incremental         Thu Jan 18 10:39:57 2024                34
. -------------------------
. 
. Secondary chain 3 of 4:
. -------------------------
. Chain start time: Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024
. Chain end time: Fri Apr 19 11:28:44 2024
. Number of contained backup sets: 13
. Total number of contained volumes: 4283
.  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
.                 Full         Thu Jan 25 08:54:41 2024              3822
.          Incremental         Thu Feb  1 18:21:24 2024                23
.          Incremental         Thu Feb  8 09:39:48 2024                45
.          Incremental         Thu Feb 15 10:28:16 2024                41
.          Incremental         Thu Feb 22 10:12:09 2024                32
.          Incremental         Thu Feb 29 09:25:02 2024                18
.          Incremental         Thu Mar  7 10:01:17 2024                58
.          Incremental         Thu Mar 14 09:40:59 2024                41
.          Incremental         Thu Mar 21 09:55:08 2024                51
.          Incremental         Sun Mar 31 12:12:12 2024                31
.          Incremental         Thu Apr  4 11:41:18 2024                25
.          Incremental         Thu Apr 11 10:38:02 2024                56
.          Incremental         Fri Apr 19 11:28:44 2024                40
. -------------------------
. 
. Secondary chain 4 of 4:
. -------------------------
. Chain start time: Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024
. Chain end time: Thu May  2 10:31:53 2024
. Number of contained backup sets: 2
. Total number of contained volumes: 3904
.  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
.                 Full         Fri Apr 26 11:10:58 2024              3872
.          Incremental         Thu May  2 10:31:53 2024                32
. -------------------------
. 
. No backup chains with active signatures found
. Also found 0 backup sets not part of any chain,
. and 1 incomplete backup set.
. These may be deleted by running duplicity with the  cleanup  command.

DEBUG 1 
. Releasing lockfile b /home/yndchrqw/.cache/deja-dup/vgsnmsvutddoxjgxxabmpyjqttjegflw/lockfile 

INFO 1 
. Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-xsm1_184-tempdir

ERROR 30 CollectionsError 
. Traceback (innermost last):
.   File  /qja/vnd/sjegmhiab , line 92, in <module>
.     with_tempdir(main)
.   File  /qja/vnd/sjegmhiab , line 75, in with_tempdir
.     fn()
.   File  /qja/dpb/djswvab/fefl-hiknjywt/sjegmhiab/qjb_jkgk.ge , line 1568, in main
.     do_backup(action)
.   File  /qja/dpb/djswvab/fefl-hiknjywt/sjegmhiab/qjb_jkgk.ge , line 1655, in do_backup
.     list_current(col_stats)
.   File  /qja/dpb/djswvab/fefl-hiknjywt/sjegmhiab/qjb_jkgk.ge , line 708, in list_current
.     sig_chain = mlb_rptte.ukh_gihcmxtni_qgpmv_sw_jxlc(vrhh)
.   File  /qja/dpb/djswvab/fefl-hiknjywt/sjegmhiab/per_fiuntlsqsce.ra , line 1035, in get_signature_chain_at_time
.     raise CollectionsError(u No signature chains found )
.  udutsugnr.ory_uinaxxmtfrh.gbjggrfgevnjtprh: No signature chains found

Does anyone have any ideas about what my next steps might be? I would really like to be able to recover this data.

You may get some clues from here, from what I read you simply can not use a Google Drive in the way you tried. https://discourse.gnome.org/t/duplicity-throwing-an-exception-on-restore-and-on-backup/17430 You also may want to try the deja dup support site.

The standard way of linking Google Drive does have a lot of limitations and it's not a true remote drive share, it's just meant for basic file copy I think. e.g. I could not get my backup rsync scripts to work on a Google Drive. I since switched to google-drive-ocamlfuse which IS just like having a normal drive share and does support rsync at least. I can't say for deja-dup as I backup locally and then rsync to Google Drive. But you could try that. It's not a 1-click install but once setup and OAuth done it works perfectly: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

looks like a more complex problem. you should try posting the issue on the duplicity mailing list https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/duplicity-talk or open a ticket on https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues as deja-dup is merely a frontend for duplicity.

Are you using the Deja-dup Google Drive section from Deja-Dup->menu->preferences->location which is a drop down menu to select your Google drive? I suspect it will not work if you don't use it that way.
